# In iOS/Android/Facebook/Twitter policy is it ok to auto login the user without have user to click the login button?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-login, google-signin

In more detail of my scenario:

1) User have clicked the login button (By Twitter, Facebook or Google etc) once and they approved to login in my iOS/Android app.

2) Then my API server will provide the user a session token to access our API server and my iOS/Android app will store this token in device for future access until this session token is expired.

3) When session token expired, I will need user to refresh their SNS (Twitter, Facebook, Google token) and give it me.

For 3, is it ok to without letting user to click the Login button again and silently perform the login to external login provider?

I can imagine on the iOS/Android app, the user will see Facebook login prompt and disappear automatically, I wonder if that's ok for Android/iOS/Facebook policy :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the policy when there is UI to get consent from user you should give the control to user to manually provide the consent like clicking on the button to login.

Comment: So when my api server session token expires, I will have to display Login page to the user every time?  If my session token is so short life, user will have to login every time?  Or is there any way I can refresh their login without having them to relogin?

Comment: In case of facebook you can have long life span token that is having 60 days validity

Comment: So you mean I will also cache the Facebook token and keep on reusing it until it expires?

Comment: yes.And if you are using fb sdk then the sdk suppose to handle this thing rather than you do manually

Comment: But I am curious why I never seen app that will ask me to login with Facebook again?   Its always just login once and forever :/

Comment: Yeah that is permission thing you give facebook. Thats once in lifetime.And moreover once you login to your app via facebook why to bother about the session token of fb. You just never log the user out until the user manually do that.

Comment: So that's mean once the user have logged into facebook in our app, all I need to do is the retrieve the Facebook access token, if the Facebook access token is expired, the SDK will automatically handle and give me a new token without prompt anything to user?

Comment: Here if the token expires also you should not bother because for your app facebook login is just the entry point nothing else

Comment: And for the token from your api server you should handle the renewal mechanism manually.